# Typescript: Get key from object with indexed signature

Tags: typescript

I'm importing the following type and function from a TypeScript module:

```
type Attributes = {
  [key: string]: number;
};

function Fn<KeysOfAttributes extends string>(opts: { attributes: Attributes }): any {
  // ...
}
```

I can't modify the code above.

Then I implement the following code to my own module:

```
// variant 1
const attributes = { // this object is hard coded (not dynamically generated)
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 3
};

type Type = typeof attributes;
type Keys = keyof Type;

Fn<Keys>({
  attributes
});
```

Everything works perfect. Now I want to assign the type `Attributes` type to the constant `attribute`, because I want to be sure that the keys are string and the values are numbers. So I modify my code:

```
// variant 2
const attributes: Attributes = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 3
};

type Type = typeof attributes;// equals {[key: string]: number;}
type Keys = keyof Type;// equals string | number. Why ?

Fn<Keys>({// Here, I would like Keys to be "foo" | "bar" | "baz", instead I have string | number
  attributes
});
```

I get the following error on the `Fn<Keys>({` line:

```
Type 'string | number' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2344)
```

I don't understand why the type `Keys` equals `string | number`, when the index signature specifically specifies that the key is a string?

How can I ensure that the `"foo" | "bar" | "baz"` type gets passed as a type argument instead of `string | number`?

I can live with the first variant, but I don't understand why the second one doesn't work.
Any idea?

Many thanks

Comment: You widened the type to a string-indexed type and the compiler dutifully expects that it could have any keys whatsoever.  That is, nothing prevents some code anywhere in your program from doing `attributes.potato = 123`.  So `keyof typeof attributes` is `string` (well, `| number` as a convenience).  If you want the best of both worlds make a helper function like `const asAttributes = <A extends Attributes>(a:A) => a` and then call it as `const attributes = asAttributes({foo: 1, bar: 2, baz:3});`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I ensure that the "foo" | "bar" | "baz" type gets passed as a type argument instead of string | number?

You can achieve this by introducing generic type parameter for `attributes`:

```
type Attributes = {
  [key: string]: number;
};

function Fn<KeysOfAttributes extends keyof T, T extends Attributes>(opts: { attributes: T }): any {
  // ...
}

const attributes = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 3,
};

Fn({
  attributes
});
```

Typescript will be able to infer the types on its own, so you won't even need the `Type` and `Keys`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Attributes%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Fn%3CKeysOfAttributes%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%20T%20extends%20Attributes%3E(opts%3A%20%7B%20attributes%3A%20T%20%7D)%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20attributes%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20baz%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AFn(%7B%0D%0A%20%20attributes%0D%0A%7D)%3B)